# Opening other preference page with Link

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm trying to link to another preference page from my custom made one. 
I have a `FieldEditorPreferencePage`, and made a custom `LinkFieldEditor` which extends `FieldEditor` so I can add it to the preference page.

```
        LinkFieldEditor linkField = new LinkFieldEditor("Click here for more options!", getFieldEditorParent());
    SelectionAdapter adapter = new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
            PreferenceDialog pref = PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(getShell(), HTML_PREF_ID, null, null);
            if (pref != null) {
                pref.open();
            }
        }
    };
    linkField.addSelectionListener(adapter);
    return linkField;
```

I'm trying to link to `Web -> HTML Files -> Editor`. The `HTML_PREF_ID is "org.eclipse.wst.html.core"`. I used this ID to change its preferences programatically, so I know its a valid ID. But when I click the link nothing happens. I debugged it and the `PreferenceDialog pref` is not null.

[image]

Comment: That's a bundle ID, not a preference page ID. You shouldn't be tampering with another bundle's preferences anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id you specify to `createPreferenceDialogOn` is the id of the preference page declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` extension point, **not** the preference store id.

For the HTML editor page this id is `org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.preferences.source`

Note: You should not need to call `open`. Since you already have the preferences open the call to `createPreferenceDialogOn` should just switch to currently selected preference page.